# How to delete/disable only certain types of mobs in my bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I delete/disable certain enemies (ie: enderman, skeletons, spiders, etc) in Bukkit 1.6.4?

I want to make a server that only has zombies.

Comment: This is actually a good question.

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin called DiableMobs.  It allows you to select only certain mobs to disable or allow. I have used it with 1.4 and it worked for me flawlessly.  They are updated for 1.6.  You can download the plugin from the [BukkitDev website.](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/disablemobsbukkit/)